# AES CBC algorithm

Tags: java

Someone can help me with aes cbc algorithm? I have some method which return   string more than 192 chars but I need to get 192!
I use next method. I've read a lot of articles but I don't get it how to do that.. Maybe someone have some instance how to resolve it?? I used to web aes encrypted http://www.cryptogrium.com/aes-encryption-online-ecb.html and I got 192 chars, but I can't do that with my method

```
private static byte[] iv = "0000000000000000".getBytes();
public static String encrypt(String content, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] input = content.getBytes("utf-8");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(key.getBytes("utf-8"));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary (cipherText);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example with actual input and key?

Comment: Ok, if this is the actual input contained in `content` then I am assuming that the method returns a string that is 384 characters (twice the length of the input)?

Comment: Yes, you right. I suppose it's because of convert to hex

Comment: Exactly. So your output is actually 192 bytes, but the conversion to hex doubles that.

Comment: How can I avoid it?

Comment: The site in your link probably converts the input to binary. If your try to change the last character in your input on that page to an 'x', it says invalid input. It only seems to accept hexadecimal characters.

Comment: It means that I can't avoid it? right?

Comment: Well, it depends if you want the returned object to be a printable string or simply a `byte[]`. Good ciphers are practically indistinguishable from random data, so any string using that will wind up with plenty of non-printable characters. It boils down to if you absolutely need the string to be printable, then it cannot be avoided. What about changing the input and return type to `byte[]`?